# xs="0" in Reactstrap is not working for mobile view

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to set column to be invisible in the mobile view. Setting 12 for the content works but 0 for the sidebar column doesn't - (it renders full width). How can I achieve this?

I tried to set Collapse around the first column, which didn't work. I wanted to ask to learn the best practice. Thanks.

```
<Row>
    <Col xs="0" sm="3">
        <Sidebar></Sidebar>
    </Col>
    <Col xs="12" sm="9">
        ... Rest of the content here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer.

I added the following classes to the sidebar wrapper. I believe this is missing in reactstrap.

```
<Col xs="0" sm="3" className="d-none d-lg-block">
    <Sidebar></Sidebar>
</Col>
<Col xs="12" sm="9">
```